# Behavioral testing with jMockit to check if function is called or not

Tags: java, junit, testng, jmockit, jmock

I want to check whether the function is been called or not. I have to do it with jMockit where function is of type `void`. I also would like to know how to do a unit testing of a function with `void` as return type.

I want to check the code given below. How would I do it? All this functions are assumptions just to make understanding of problem clear.

How would I check if function `logdata`,`processdata` is being called? And how do I write **testcases** for `checkdata` function. (I am using TestNG tool.)

```
public void checkdata(int a, int b) {
     logdata(a, b);
     int c = a * b;
     processdata(c);
}
```

Comment: Mock `logdata` and `processdata`, create an expectations object for them, run test, check expectations were satisfied

Comment: Are `logdata()` and `processdata()` **private**?

Comment: You can check if the methods have been called in a newStrictExpectations block and using the attribute "times=1" for each one. Also you can do this in a verification block if you not bother about the results. If the methods are private use the new MockUp<ClassName> in an expectation block to mock the returned results and also "times" attribute to specify if the methods have been called.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the methods have been called in a newStrictExpectations block and using the attribute "times=1" for each one. Also you can do this in a verification block if you not bother about the results. If the methods are private use the new MockUp in an expectation block to mock the returned results and also "times" attribute to specify if the methods have been called.